# MongoError: not authorized on SessionDB to execute command { listIndexes: "sessions", cursor: {} }

Tags: mongodb

I have enabled authentication in my mongo db and have added a user as follows.

```
db.createUser({
  user: "myuser",
  pwd: "abc123",
  roles: [ "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
});
```

I am using this user to run a express node server. The database connects successfully but then fails with the following exception.

```
Unhandled rejection MongoError: not authorized on SessionDB to execute command { listIndexes: "sessions", cursor: {} }
    at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/myuser/code/test_project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at queryCallback (/Users/myuser/code/test_project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:212:36)
    at /Users/myuser/code/test_project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

Unhandled rejection MongoError: not authorized on SessionDB to execute command { listIndexes: "sessions", cursor: {} }
    at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/myuser/code/test_project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at queryCallback (/Users/myuser/code/test_project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:212:36)
    at /Users/myuser/code/test_project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

I read the documentation for mongodb and it says that indexes are saved in system collection but `read` builtin role should allow the user to access the same. I have tried giving my user `readAnyDatabase` and `read` builtin roles, I also tried many other ways to make it work but it still gives the same exception.

I can see that similar questions have been asked before on this forum but they do not provide any description or a solution.

Comment: Where did you create the user? On the `admin` database or elsewhere?

Comment: All the users that I have created are in `admin` database

Comment: `SessionDB` is this using passport or something? Have you possibly defined a different user for that connection?

Comment: `SessionDB` is created by express-session module of nodejs.

Comment: Exactly. Is that using the same connection credentials as your application or are they different? You probably need to show your connection code and how you are configuring the "sessions" part as well. Edit your question and add these details. Also include which MongoDB version you are using. Putting more detail into the question is preferable to long conversations in comments. Give people enough information so they can reproduce the problem themselves. Or spot the problem.

Comment: Good point ! I will get back to you in some time. Thanks

Comment: It got resolved! I totally forgot the express session creates its own mongo client because I am making a separate connection to the same database for some other purpose and I thought that the client which was failing.

Comment: Just had to put the credentials in the connection string for express session.

Comment: That's what it looked like. There probably is an option that allows you to pass in the existing connection credentials if you look at the documentation. That should save you setting up different connection credentials

Comment: sure I'll have a look. Thanks !